# Repeatedly send email with python on time interval

Tags: python, email

I want to make a python script that sends an email with an attachment (txt) every 30 minutes. Here is my code to send the email with the attachment. It's working without any problems. However, I need help to figure out how to send this on a time schedule.

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email import encoders
import os.path

email = 'myaddress@gmail.com'
password = 'password'
send_to_email = 'sentoaddreess@gmail.com'
subject = 'This is the subject'
message = 'This is my message'
file_location = 'C:\\Users\\You\\Desktop\\attach.txt'

msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg['From'] = email
msg['To'] = send_to_email
msg['Subject'] = subject

msg.attach(MIMEText(message, 'plain'))

filename = os.path.basename(file_location)
attachment = open(file_location, "rb")
part = MIMEBase('application', 'octet-stream')
part.set_payload((attachment).read())
encoders.encode_base64(part)
part.add_header('Content-Disposition', "attachment; filename= %s" % filename)

msg.attach(part)

server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
server.starttls()
server.login(email, password)
text = msg.as_string()
server.sendmail(email, send_to_email, text)
server.quit()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two options for you

1. You can look into scheduling your python script to run at a certain time interval. This means, each script run would send one email, and you would stop the automated task rather than stopping the script when you want the emails to stop. If you're running Windows OS, they have a built in application called [Task Scheduler](https://www.esri.com/arcgis-blog/products/product/analytics/scheduling-a-python-script-or-model-to-run-at-a-prescribed-time/) to manage this for you.
2. Option two is to use the time.sleep() function. This method would mean the script would continue to run and shoot off an email every 30 minutes. The script would have to be stopped when you want the emails to stop.

   ```
   import time
   while True:
       {insert your email send code here}
       time.sleep(60*30) # this is in seconds, so 60 seconds x 30 mins
   ```

Comment: Make sure you're indenting all of your code after the `while True:`. The whole thing should be an indented block